# Sum over values of auxiliary function gets arbitrary big, justification

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Let $f : \mathbb N_{>0} \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ be a function satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-f(n)} = \infty$ (like $f(n) = \log n$). Define
$$
 F(n) = \left\lfloor \log_2\left( \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-f(i)} \right)\right\rfloor.
$$
Why do we have $\sum_{F(n) = m} 2^{-f(n)} \ge 2^m - 1$?

Comment: Does $\log$ denote the base-$2$ logarithm here?

Comment: Yes, $\log = \log_2$.

Comment: Is $f(k)\ge0$ or is $f(k)\ge1$? (People use $\mathbb{N}$ is different ways)

Comment: @robjohn: $f(k) \ge 0$.

Comment: @Stefan: It would be nice to clarify these things in the question itself. Furthermore, $f(n)=\log(n)$ sends $\mathbb{N}_{\gt0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ and not $\mathbb{N}$. Since the result is true for functions from $\mathbb{N}_{\gt0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, it might be a simple change (that won't affect the current answers) to have $f:\mathbb{N}_{\gt0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$.

Comment: @robjohn: Yes, I changed it, I have taken this from a derivation in a textbook on partial recursive functions, and I guess there $\log n$ is read as $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$ I guess without saying, but anyway as it holds in either case, if real or integer valued the answers remain valid.

Comment: @Stefan: I hope you don't mind, but I also changed the $\log$ to $\log_2$

Comment: @robjohn: No, thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2^{-f(n)} > 0$, we know that $F$ is non-decreasing. Also, since $\sum 2^{-f(n)} = +\infty$, $F$ is unbounded.

If $F$ attains the value $m$, then there is a smallest value $a$ with $F(a) = m$, and a smallest value $b$ with $F(b) \geqslant m+1$. Then we have by definition of $F$

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{a-1} 2^{-f(n)} < 2^m\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{n = 1}^b 2^{-f(n)} \geqslant 2^{m+1}.$$

It then follows that

$$\sum_{F(n) = m} 2^{-f(n)} = \sum_{n = a}^{b-1} 2^{-f(n)} > 2^{m+1} - 2^{-f(b)} - 2^m = 2^m - 2^{-f(b)} \geqslant 2^m - 1,$$

since $2^{-f(b)} \leqslant 1.$

If $F$ does not attain the value $m$, then we have

$$\sum_{F(n) = m} 2^{-f(n)} = 0,$$

so we need to see that $m \leqslant 0$ to have $2^m - 1 \leqslant 0$.

Now suppose that $m > 0$ and $b$ is the smallest positive integer with $F(b) > m$. Then we have

$$\sum_{n = 1}^b 2^{-f(n)} \geqslant 2^{m+1} \geqslant 4,$$

so in particular $b \geqslant 4$, and

$$2^{m+1} > \sum_{n = 1}^{b-1} 2^{-f(n)} = \sum_{n = 1}^b 2^{-f(n)} - 2^{-f(b)} \geqslant 2^{m+1}-1 \geqslant 2^m,$$

so we have $F(b-1) = m$, and $F$ does not skip the value $m$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$F(n)=m$ means that
$$
2^m\le\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-f(k)}\lt2^{m+1}\tag{1}
$$
Let $n_m$ be the smallest $n$ so that $F(n)=m$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n_m-1}2^{-f(k)}\lt2^m\tag{2}
$$
Since $f(k)\ge0$, we have $2^{-f(k)}\le1$. Therefore, since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n_{m+1}}2^{-f(k)}\ge2^{m+1}\tag{3}
$$
we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n_{m+1}-1}2^{-f(k)}\ge2^{m+1}-1\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, subtracting $(2)$ from $(4)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{F(k)=m}2^{-f(k)}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n_{m+1}-1}2^{-f(k)}-\sum_{k=1}^{n_m-1}2^{-f(k)}\\[6pt]
&\gt2^m-1\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice derivation too!